# CGContextShowGlyphsAtPoint DEPRECATED

Tags: ios7, fonts, drawrect, core-text, uifont

After spending quite a bit of time to display "Thai Phonetic YK" fonts in an iPhone app. I finally got things sorted out and working.

Though it is functionning there is still a complaint (warning) from the compiler about one line of code in the (void)drawRect: method of my class performing the display.

```
CGContextShowGlyphsAtPoint(context, 20, 50, textToPrint, textLength);
```

The compiler tells me that this code is DEPRECATED. My question is “How am I supposed to change it?”.
Even though I searched the net for an answer, I didn’t find any thing clear.
The documentation says something like “Use Core Text instead” which is far too vague to be considered as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Core Graphics:

```
void CGContextShowGlyphsAtPoint (
   CGContextRef context,
   CGFloat x,
   CGFloat y,
   const CGGlyph glyphs[],
   size_t count
);
```

Core Text:

```
void CTFontDrawGlyphs (
   CTFontRef font,
   const CGGlyph glyphs[],
   const CGPoint positions[],
   size_t count,
   CGContextRef context
);
```

The Core Text version requires a CTFontRef (in the Core Graphics version, the font is expected to be set in the context).

You can obtain a CTFontRef from a UIFont:

```
    CTFontRef ctFont = CTFontCreateWithName( (__bridge CFStringRef)uiFont.fontName, uiFont.pointSize, NULL);
```

The CT version also requires an array of points, one for each glyph. Assuming you were drawing a single glyph with the CG code, you could create the array like this:

```
        CGPoint point = CGPointMake(x, y);
        const CGPoint* positions = &point;
```

This change does mean you will need a point position for each glyph. In my case the extra work was minimal:  I was advancing the typesetter one character at a time (for curved text) so I had to do this calculation anyway.

You may be able to typeset one text run at a time with CTRun:

```
  void CTRunDraw ( 
      CTRunRef run, 
      CGContextRef context, 
      CFRange range );
```

That could save you the trouble of iterating over each glyph. You could use it something like this...

```
CGContextSetTextMatrix(context, CGAffineTransformIdentity);
CTLineRef line = CTLineCreateWithAttributedString(
      (__bridge CFTypeRef)self.attributedString);

  CFArrayRef runs = CTLineGetGlyphRuns(line);
  CFIndex runCount = CFArrayGetCount(runs);
  for (CFIndex runIndex = 0; runIndex < runCount; ++runIndex) {
      CTRunRef run = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(runs, runIndex);
      [self adjustContextForRun:run];
       CTRunDraw (run, context, 0)
 }
```

(thats just a sketch, implementation will depend on your needs, and i haven't tested the code)

`adjustContextForRun` would be responsible for setting things like font and initial draw position for the run.

Each CTRun represents a subrange of an attributed string where all of the attributes are the same. IF you don't vary attributes over a line, you can abstract this further:

```
  CTLineDraw(line, context);
```

I don't know if that level of abstraction would work in your case (i am only used to working with Latin fonts), but its worth knowing it's there, saves a lot of lower-level trouble.

You can set the initial drawing position for the text with this:

```
 void CGContextSetTextPosition ( 
    CGContextRef c, 
    CGFloat x, 
    CGFloat y );
```